# Create Table with two lists python

Tags: python, pandas, list, create-table

I have two lists. I have a list of table titles(title_df). My other list is from my contents (prediction_df) to be sorted by titles. I want to populate my contents by titles and create a table in the result.

```
title_df=['a','b']

prediction_df=['1','2','3','800800','802100','800905']
```

My table has three rows and two columns

Comment: Hi, what were your attempts and where did they fail at (if at all)? I see you accepted an answer but do you *really* understand what's going on there (e.g., why is `order="F"` needed)? If you shared your attempts, maybe the answerers could have pointed what's missing and/or have built their answers on top of it., leading to a better understanding.

Comment: Hi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973722/how-does-numpy-reshape-with-order-f-workI solved the details from this link. The question I asked contains only a small part of the problem at hand. I am trying to carry out a different study based on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), `2` is for 2 columns and `-1` is for count number of rows by data, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(prediction_df, (-1,2), order='F'), columns=title_df)
print (df)
   a       b
0  1  800800
1  2  802100
2  3  800905
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If prediction_df= [[['1','2','3']],[['800800','802100','800905']]], how would my management change?

Comment: @ysmnrn.dll - Then use `df = pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in prediction_df], index=title_df).T`

Comment: @ysmnrn.dll - if `prediction_df= [['1','2','3'],['800800','802100','800905']]` then `df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_df, index=title_df).T`